# Black Scholes Stochastic Taylor expansion question

Tags: black-scholes, stochastic-processes

I am currently deriving Black-Scholes formula, and i get the following equation when Im doing the Tayler expansion:

$dG=\frac{\partial G}{\partial S}dS+\frac{\partial G}{\partial t}dt+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^{2}G}{\partial S^{2}}dS^{2}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^{2}G}{\partial t^{2}}dt^{2}+\frac{\partial^{2}G}{\partial S\partial t}dSdt$

Since it is a stochastic process, we need the to take into account the $\frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^{2} G}{\partial S^{2}} d S^{2}$ part, since $d S^{2}=\sigma^{2} S^{2} d t$, which means that this term also has an effect on $dG$ (since expression is linear in $dt$).

Now, what I dont understand, is why we need $dG$ to be linear? Why can't we use second order terms?

I suspect the answer is quite straight forward, but I cant seem to wrap my head around it.

Comment: This is not a Taylor expansion, you need to apply Ito's lemma on G = G(S, t). The result follows immediately using this. As for the intuition, $dS^n$ with $n>2$ will fade away indeed.

Answer (score 2):

Oh i think i got it. We are only considering the time step $dt$, which is why, first of all we need $\frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^{2} G}{\partial S^{2}} d S^{2}$, and also why we remove: $\frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^{2} G}{\partial t^{2}} d t^{2}+\frac{\partial^{2} G}{\partial S \partial t} d S d t$